# Do web launch apps conform to Apple iOS App Store / Google Play App store

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Does some know, if apps, which immediately after launch opens a system browser window, conform to App Store / Play Store guidelines?

Or does an app need to show a screen and wait for users to take action?

Comment: Why not use an internal Webview ?

Comment: Would be an option, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an explicit rules in [Apple's review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality) for the App Store.

But it seems to be that Apple would reject an app which would only open the navigator :

> Apple rejects applications that do not:
>
> have a user experience that feels like an "app" feel "at home" in the
>   iOS ecosystem offer a differentiation from a mobile web experience

From : [PhoneGap advice on dealing with Apple application rejections](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/apple-application-rejections-and-phonegap-advice.html)

So I would strongly suggest using an [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: You might not even be able to use just a webview—[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) §2.12 says "Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected"

Comment: @0942v8653 Thank you very much for a valuable comment!